# Cannot read property from my document.forms

Tags: javascript

i have this `js` code on my page:

```
var mail = 'idEmail';
value(mail);
//function returning the value of an input
function value(input){
  return eval('window.document.Search.'+input).value;
}
```

I have this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'idEmail' of undefined
```

Why when i change `return eval('window.document.Search.'+input).value;` by `return eval('window.document.forms['Search'].'+input).value;` it's work?

```
document.forms["general"]
or
document.forms[0]
or
document.general
```

it's the same

Comment: because you forgot `.forms` in the first version

Comment: Oh for crying out loud, do away with the `eval` nonsense ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable

Answer (score 1):

Because you forgot the `forms` part:

```
return eval('window.document.forms.Search.'+input).value;
```

Note that `eval` is evil. You might as well do:

```
return document.forms.Search[input].value;
```

Comment: `return document.forms.Search[input].value;`

Comment: this is why eval is evil [Why is using the JavaScript eval function a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea)

Answer (score 1):

In your `function` you are trying to access a property of an `undefined` object, in fact `.Search` isn't a property of `window.document` but of `window.document.forms` instead, change it like this:

```
function value(input){
  return window.document.forms.Search[input].value;
}
```

**Note:**

It's better to avoid using `eval`, you can get rid of it in your function.